# SQL Server 2008 R2: Exact match of multiple values in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
create table person
(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    games varchar(20)
);

insert into person values(1,'A','Cricket'),(1,'A','F1'),(2,'B','Cricket'),(3,'C','Cricket'),(3,'C','F1')
```

Expected result:

```
id name games
--------------
1   A   Cricket
1   A   F1
3   C   Cricket
3   C   F1
```

My Try 1:

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERe games = 'Cricket' 
AND games = 'F1'
```

Output: Nothing

My Try 2:

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERe games IN('Cricket','F1')
```

Output:

```
id  name    games
-------------------
1   A   Cricket
1   A   F1
2   B   Cricket     ---This should not come
3   C   Cricket
3   C   F1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, grouping it by name wise on games and then select which has participate in more than 1 game.

```
select a.* from 
person as a,
(
    select id,count(*) as total 
    from
    person
    where
    games in ('Cricket','F1')
    group by id,name
)as b
where
a.id = b.id
and b.total >=2
```

output :

```
id  name    games
1   A       Cricket
1   A       F1
3   C       Cricket
3   C       F1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM person a
WHERE 
    games IN('Cricket','F1')    AND
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Id)
        FROM person
        WHERE 
            Id =  a.Id
    ) = 2
```

Or more universal

```
;WITH model AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Cricket'),('F1')) a(Games)
)
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    person a
INNER JOIN
    model   b
ON
    a.games = b.games
WHERE   
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Id)
        FROM person
        WHERE 
            Id =  a.Id
    ) =
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM model
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so close :)

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE games IN ('Cricket','F1') AND Name IN ('A', 'C')
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)-clause to count the number of games per id within your defined filter:

```
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *,
    COUNT(id) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS cnt
    FROM person
    WHERE games IN('Cricket','F1')
)
SELECT id, name, games FROM t
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also count where there is more than 1 value (then there is multiple values and then inner join them with the table to match the rows)

```
select x.id,b.games,b.name from (
select id,count(id) as Total from person

group by id
having count(id) > 1
) x
inner join person b on x.id = b.id
```

**Result**

[image]